# how to get array elements in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
In html
<select class="element-margin-top" ng-model="vm.selectedRole" ng-options="(roleName,enabled) in vm.roleNames">
                <option value="">All Roles</option>{{vm.roles[0]}}
            </select>
```

I want to display all the array elements in select options.I dont understand what is going on in this.It is giving me error related to (roleName,enabled) in vm.roleNames

```
In js:
 var vm = this;
 vm.roleNames = ['SuperAdmin','Admin','Retailer','Manufacturer'];
 vm.selectedRole = vm.roleNames[-1];
```

I want first element to be selected by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In html:

```
<select class="element-margin-top" ng-model="vm.selectedOption">
                    <option value="">All Roles</option>
                    <option ng-repeat="item in vm.optionNames" value="{{item}}">{{item}}</option>
                </select>
```

in js:-

```
vm.optionNames = ['User', 'Account', 'Brand'];
  vm.selectedOption = vm.optionNames[-1];
```

try reading http://www.undefinednull.com/2014/08/11/a-brief-walk-through-of-the-ng-options-in-angularjs/

Answer (score 2):

`ng-options="(roleName,enabled) in vm.roleNames"` in this case, `vm.roleNames` is an array, so, `roleName` is the `index` and `enabled` is the real `"roleName"`

So your code should looks like this:

```
<select class="element-margin-top" ng-model="vm.selectedRole" ng-options="(index,roleName) as roleName in vm.roleNames">
         <option value="">All Roles</option>
</select>
```

Comment: ok thanks but how I am supposed to pull elements from array to select - option

Comment: error: [ngOptions:iexp] Expected expression in form of '_select_ (as _label_)? for (_key_,)?_value_ in _collection_' but got '(index,roleName) in vm.roleNames'.

Answer (score 0):

try this , for first selected by defult you can use $first

```
<select   ng-model="selectedRole">
                        <option ng-repeat="name in roleNames "
                            ng-selected="$first" value="{{name}}">{{name}}</option>
                </select>
```

Comment: I forgot that , use $first for default first selected